# 2-dimensional random walk

Tags: markov-process

I have understood that for p=1/2 1-dimensional random walk is recurrent  but I have no idea on how to approach this ,in case of 2-dimensional random walk

[image: Question]

Comment: Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge this new account with your old.

Comment: @whuber it would be great if you could help with this

Comment: It is impossible to help with a homework question without input from the OP about textbook, background, &tc. For instance, why is [Feller's An Introduction to Probability Theory, vol. 2, Chapter XII](https://amzn.to/3pNwtuK), not providing enough material to solve this question?